# Exchange Keeper Card

Tags: fluxx

In Zombie Fluxx, if you play an Exchange Keepers Card, can you give them a Creeper and they give you a Keeper so you can match the goal?

Answer (score 3):

No, you are exchanging a keeper for a keeper, and a keeper is not a creeper.

That said, in some varieties of Fluxx (I don't have Zombie myself), certain creepers attach themselves to keeper cards you have on the table.  If that is the case, the creeper follows the keeper.  If you are trading the keeper that has an attached creeper, the other player will take the creeper as well.

Comment: In zombie, there is no attachment.

Answer (score 2):

No, a creeper is not a keeper, it's a different type of card. So it can't be affected by things that affect keepers.